# Does a limit exist at a cusp or sharp point

Tags: calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Does a limit exist at a sharp curve or point? The limit as $x \to c+$ and $x \to c-$ won't equal at a cusp right? (or would it in some cases? So depending on that, does a limit always or never or sometimes exists at a cusp.

Thanks guys

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}|x|$ exists, but of course $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Ok, but i have still not been taught about differentiable. But limits at cusps do exist. Ok thank you

Comment: Is there an example where a limit doesn't exist at a cusp?

Comment: @user5139637 if your cusp could be draw without lifting the pen, then no.

Comment: @Jesse I disagree, the $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} |x|$ does not exist. This is because the side limits exist, but they are different. And that is also why $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x = $.

Comment: @Calculemus the limit definitely does exist. The absolute value function is continuous. The limit of the difference quotient doesn’t exist - this is probably what you’re thinking of

Comment: @Calculemus, the limit is 0. In fact, |x| is a classic example of a function that is everywhere continuous but not everywhere differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** there exists a limit at a sharp point.

According to the definition of limit. Limit $L$ exists if $$\lim _{x\rightarrow n^+}f\left( x\right) =\lim _{x\rightarrow n^-}f\left( x\right) $$
The function is of course still continuous at the cusp so the limit exists and is evaluated as
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow n^+}f\left( x\right) = L =\lim _{x\rightarrow n^-}f\left( x\right) $$

Answer (score -1):

There is a mathematical way to deal with sharp edges or cusps,
if $f(x)$ is the function with sharp edge at $x=c$ then shift the origin at $(c,0)$ and then obtain fourier series for $f(x)$,
Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1\cos{x}+a_2\cos{2x}...+b_1\sin{x}+b_2\sin{2x}...$
Then, $f'(0)=\sum_{1}^{\infty}nb_n$
If you can evaluate it you could obtain the derivative at the sharp edge.

Comment: If OP has not yet learned about differentiability, then OP is certainly not aware of Fourier series.

Answer (score -1):

I asked myself this question as well and I tried to answer it based on the following example f(x)=|x| at the point x=0.

a) Does the limit exist at x=0?

b) Does the derivative exist at x=0?

One definition of a convergent functions is;

Let $f:D\to R$ be a function and a a cluster point of D. The function converges in a, if for $\forall a_n\in D$\{a}, which converges to a $f(a_n)$ converges as well. Based on the definition we can evaluate both questions;

a) Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ be the sequence approaching 0 from the right and

$a_n=-\frac{1}{n}$ be the sequence approaching 0 from the left, then;

$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}|+\frac{1}{n}|=0$
$\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}|-\frac{1}{n}|=0$

Thus the limit exists since $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$=$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$

b)

$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}\frac{f(a+a_n)-f(a)}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}\frac{f(0+\frac{1}{n})-f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}\frac{|0+\frac{1}{n}|-|0|}{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(a+a_n)-f(a)}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}\frac{f(a-\frac{1}{n})-f(a)}{-\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}\frac{f(0-\frac{1}{n})-f(0)}{-\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}\frac{|0-\frac{1}{n}|-|0|}{-\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty^+}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{-\frac{1}{n}}=-1$

The limits are not equal and hence the derivative of the function at x=0 does not exist.

The above is not a proof but only an example. In general the limit exists for all x in the interior of the domain. The derivative however does not necessarily exist for all continuous functions.